# Cannot update a Django user profile

Tags: python, django

I have a react app interacting with django to create and update user profiles. I am encountering this error message when I try to update a user profile, specifically the first name and last name properties I get a response that indicates that my user profile has not been updated

```
{"username":"***","email":"emmanuelsibanda21@gmail.com","password":"****","first_name":"","last_name":""}
```

This is what I have in my urls.py:

```
path('update_profile/<int:pk>', views.UpdateProfileView.as_view(), name='update_profile'),
```

UpdateProfileView:

```
class UpdateProfileView(generics.UpdateAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UpdateUserSerializer
    def profile(request):
        if request.method == 'PUT':
            try:
                user = User.objects.get(id=request.user.id)
                serializer_user = UpdateUserSerializer(user, many=True)
                if serializer_user.is_valid():
                    serializer_user.save()
                    return Response(serializer_user)
            except User.DoesNotExist:
                return Response(data='no such user!', status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

UpdateUserSerializer:

```
class UpdateUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password', 'first_name', 'last_name']
        extra_kwargs = {'username': {'required': False},
                        'email': {'required': False},
                        'password': {'required': False},
                        'first_name': {'required': False},
                        'last_name': {'required': False}}


        def validate_email(self, value):
            user = self.context['request'].user
            if User.objects.exclude(pk=user.pk).filter(email=value).exists():
                raise serializers.ValidationError({"email": "This email is already in use."})
            return value

        def validate_username(self, value):
            user = self.context['request'].user
            if User.objects.exclude(pk=user.pk).filter(username=value).exists():
                raise serializers.ValidationError({"username": "This username is already in use."})
            return value

        def update(self, instance, validated_data):
            user = self.context['request'].user

            if user.pk != instance.pk:
                raise serializers.ValidationError({"authorize": "You don't have permission for this user."})

            instance.first_name = validated_data['first_name']
            instance.last_name = validated_data['last_name']
            instance.email = validated_data['email']
            instance.username = validated_data['username']

            instance.save()

            return instance
```

Any ideas where I am going wrong? To summarize one more time; I would like to enable a user to successfully update the first name and last name properties associated with a particular user

Answer (score 0):

Edit `urls.py` like this

```
path('update_profile/<int:pk>/', views.UpdateProfileView.as_view(), name='update_profile'),
```

I hope this will work